# Deciding if $m \not \in \{x^2 \bmod p : x \in \mathbb N\}$, also cardinality

Tags: modular-arithmetic

Let $S_p = \{x^2 \bmod p : x\in\mathbb N\}$, with $p$ prime.

Is there an efficient way to determine if an arbitrary $m \not \in S_p$, where $m \in\mathbb N \bmod p$, without generating $S_p$?

E.g. $S_5 = \{0, 1, 4\}$, $m \in \{2, 3\}$.

Also is there a way to estimate $|S_p|$?

Comment: $\mathbb{N}^2$ stands for the cartesian product, not for the squares of the natural numbers.

Comment: @Aravind - can you suggest a correct notation?

Comment: You can use $\{x^2 \text{ mod p }: x \in \mathbb{N}\}$.

Comment: Can someone review the edit suggested by an anonymous user? I don't seem to have the privileges to accept or reject it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if a number is a square or non-square mod $p$, you can use Euler's criterion: compute $a^{\frac{p-1}{2}}$ (mod p) and check if it is equal to 1 or -1.

The number of squares is $(p+1)/2$ as the earlier answer shows.

Comment: Is **a** the number we're checking?

Comment: Yes, $a$ is the number we're checking.

Comment: Thank you. Of note is that aⁿ is easily optimized to O(log₂(n)) modular multiplications.